# Use keyboard as Simulink 3D Joystick?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is it possible to use the keyboard instead of the joystick or the spacemouse block in simulink ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24216-simulink-keyboard-input-v2

Use this function in a "Level-2 M-file S-Function" block. The first output gives the last key pressed. The second output gives 1 if a key is pressed, 0 otherwise.